# How to interpret ROC curve with confusion matrix and F1 score?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, roc, validation, auc

I have implemented a random forest classifier to do a binary classification in highly imbalanced class. As the performance measurements, ROC and the f1 score was considered. However, the ROC curve gives AUC of 1 which corresponding to the perfect value and I am a little bit worried about it since it is the perfect solution. I have attached the ROC curve confusion matrix below and the F1 score is 0.99942. Can someone interpret these results to check if the model is good or bad?

```
dfinput =pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "../data.csv"))
dfoutput = dfinput["target"]
dfinput = dfinput[selecting feature columns]
X = np.array(dfinput)
y = np.array(dfoutput)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.transform(X)
randomforestclassifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)

print("Feature Importance Started")
model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
print(model.feature_importances_)
print("Feature Importance Ended")

X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,random_state=3)
X_resampled, y_resampled = SMOTE(ratio='minority').fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
randomforestclassifier.fit(X_resampled, y_resampled)
list1 = randomforestclassifier.predict(X_test)
list2 = randomforestclassifier.predict(X_train)

prob_test = randomforestclassifier.predict_proba(X_test)
predictions = pd.DataFrame(prob_test)
predictions = predictions.iloc[:, 1]

false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, predictions)
roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)

plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic of Test set')
plt.plot(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, 'b',
label='AUC = %0.2f'% roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],'r--')
plt.xlim([-0.1,1.2])
plt.ylim([-0.1,1.2])
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()

print("F Score for test data %s "%(f1_score(y_test, list1, average='micro')  ))
```

Confusion matrix
[image: Confusion matrix]

ROC curve
[image: ROC curve]

Comment: You may be Neo from the matrix: the chosen one who has solved a problem almost perfectly. However, from my experience, I can only say that I understand your worries and highly doubt that. Without knowing anything further about the code or the data my guesses are: 1) you included an 'illegal' variable that is either the answer itself or something close to the true answer. 2) there is some problem in the evaluation logic/grouping/...

Comment: @FabianWerner I added the source code. Also when I applied cross-validation it gave good results as well.

Comment: One plot is missing: what does the feature importance look like? This might help in figuring out which feature might be the faulty one...

Comment: [7.26015980e-02 7.25199703e-02 5.44723388e-02 1.11711937e-01
 1.04243051e-01 1.20475797e-01 1.52748141e-01 9.90904056e-02
 2.12067774e-01 6.89864711e-05] these are the feature imporance values for each feature. The code of confusion matrix is directly coming from sklearn

Comment: That is good but which feature corresponds to which value?

Comment: 10 independent features were utilized and the list contains their importance values

Comment: What names do these features have (in the order in which they appear in the list)? What do they mean with respect to your target variable? You could run the same code on an artificial, self generated dataset in order to see that the code works fine.

Comment: I want to comment but without enough reputation, so I will post here as "answer". As Fabian noted, it looks very suspicious with perfect AUC on the test set, one can not help to look for data leakage. One thing you might try to debug is to remove your most important features (which you can get from your random forest classifier), refit the model, and see how the AUC changes. I would probably start by removing the feature that has feature importance about 0.2. If you see a sudden jump at some point, then it might give you some hint...